# Delete an object from a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, angular7

I have this small function (within my `Angular 7` application) which uses JavaScript `reduce()`, and locates an object within a nested array of objects. I can then proceed to update certain properties on the fly.

Now, in addition to this find logic, I would like to also `insert/delete` an object into/from the nested array.

Question is: once I do locate my object, can I push() and/or delete an object ?

```js
const input={UID:2,GUID:"",LocationName:"USA",ParentLocation:null,subs:[{UID:42,GUID:"",LocationName:"New Jersey",Description:"",subs:[{UID:3,GUID:"",LocationName:"Essex County",ParentLocation:null,"subs":[{UID:4,LocationName:"Newark",ParentLocation:3,"subs":[{"UID":49,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Doctor Smith's Office","LocationType":{"UID":2,"LocationTypeName":"Practice","Description":"other location"},"subs":[{"HostID":38,"HostName":"Ocean Host",}]}]}]}]}]};

const findUIDObj = (uid, parent) => {
  const { UID, subs } = parent;
  if (UID === uid) {
    const { subs, ...rest } = parent;
    return rest;
  }
  if (subs) return subs.reduce((found, child) => found || findUIDObj(uid, child), null);
};
console.log(findUIDObj(49, input));

var obj = findUIDObj(49, input);
delete obj;
```

For example, in my Angular 7 app, it complains if I attempt to `delete` the found object:

ex/

```
var obj = findUIDObj(49, input);
delete obj; 

  'delete' cannot be called on an identifier in strict mode.
```

Comment: As far as I understand you can't delete nested objects within strict mode. You would have to create a new object with the specified one filtered out.

Comment: `delete` not proper on arrays either...it leaves holes and doesn't change length. Use `splice()` to remove object from array so you will need to determine index within array

Comment: Also, if the object to "delete" is the root object, then what should happen? To be more consistent, your `input` object should be an array like the `subs` arrays are.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `delete` operator. I would simply return a copy of the object without the stuff that you don't need.

Comment: In strict mode you can use delete to remove properties from objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete obj` would never do what you want: first of all, it is not even an object from your input, since the function created a *new* object from the found object, excluding the `subs` property, and returned that. But more importantly, `delete` is used for deleting properties, not objects.

It seems you want to remove a matching object from its parent `subs` property. For that you would need to mutate the `subs` array, so it would exclude the matching object. For that to work in a generic way, your input should be an array. Otherwise that root object could not be removed from anything.

With that in mind, your lookup function should return the array in which the match was found and at which index. With those pieces of information you can decide to remove that element from the array, or to insert another object at that index.

Here is how it could work with removal:

```js
const input=[{UID:2,GUID:"",LocationName:"USA",ParentLocation:null,subs:[{UID:42,GUID:"",LocationName:"New Jersey",Description:"",subs:[{UID:3,GUID:"",LocationName:"Essex County",ParentLocation:null,"subs":[{UID:4,LocationName:"Newark",ParentLocation:3,"subs":[{"UID":49,"GUID":"","LocationName":"Doctor Smith's Office","LocationType":{"UID":2,"LocationTypeName":"Practice","Description":"other location"},"subs":[{"HostID":38,"HostName":"Ocean Host",}]}]}]}]}]}];

const findUIDObj = (uid, arr) => {
    if (!arr) return;
    const idx = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.UID === uid);
    if (idx > -1) return [arr, idx];
    for (const obj of arr) {
        const result = findUIDObj(uid, obj.subs);
        if (result) return result;
    }
};
console.log(findUIDObj(49, input));

const [arr, idx] = findUIDObj(49, input) || [];
if (arr) {
    arr.splice(idx, 1); // Remove object from its parent array
}
```

Comment: correct. My mistake for trying to delete an object with the `delete`  command (I should know better). And by the way, I will only be allowed to delete a leaf node in this scenario; a separate operation takes place prior to me updating this nested tree.

Comment: I never properly tested your idea in my app until today. It worked great, thank you. Where my original post above would allow me to simply locate an object and update it, your updated logic allows me to iterate each sub array and find the desired index -  `arr.findIndex()` - and then delete it via `splice()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Looking briefly at your code, I see you are using a `const` identifier to declare your data collection. We only use `const` for static data that does not change, and that’s the purpose of it. So, first of all matters, that seems to be the problem. To test it change it to `let`. Now, as for methods for data management, immutability is worthy of your consideration for many reasons, but namely Angular will rerender the entire object regardless of altering the existing object, or receiveing a new object. You can look up Immutable JavaScript to understand more. In many cases, creating immutable data management is done with a library, you can do it yourself. Basically, create a function called `copy( data )`, or something so that you pass in the original object, but you get a copy of it in return with no reference to the original object. That way one does not accidentally change the original object. To do this you can do this inside of your copy function: `return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( data )) ;`

The only problem you might run into here is deep nested objects, or objects with circular references can cause problems. I have an overriding `stringify` method to mange this in little libraries I’ve written.